# Vim glitch screen while scrolling using <C-d>

Tags: scrolling

I am using vim on wsl (ubuntu2004). It works just fine if it is slow scrolling however if I scroll it fasted using jump scrolling `<C-d>` or `<C-u>` it makes the screen have some rendering crash for a couple second.

I saw a few screen fix problem from forum, however seems it only fix another problem but not this one. here is my `.vimrc`:

```
" ----- WIN 10 SCREEN - BUF(at start) FIX -----     
" set t_ut=""

" highlight Normal ctermfg=black ctermbg=lightgrey
if &term =~ '256color'
    set t_ut=
endif

set t_u7=
```

[image: vim glitch]

Comment: what terminal do you use? cmd.exe? windows terminal? wsltty? alacritty?

Comment: does it happen with default colorscheme? with vim --clean ?

Comment: @MaximKim i'm using wsl.exe. not the win10new terminal one, but the `wsl.exe`. and no it does not happened for `vim --clean` only when I use this colorscheme (gruvbox)

Comment: and what about `vim --clean` and gruvbox colorscheme? does it happen to other colorschemes?

Comment: yes, and it even worst. some of the blank space beside text not rendered correctly

Comment: I can only fix it if I set the gruvbox `termcolors=16`, however it wil change the bg to black

Comment: PS Welcome to [vi.se]!